# Make an Html.ActionLink around an Image in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I do something similar to Html.ActionLink() except place the generated link around an Image instead of just spitting out the link?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Razor (View Engine):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/imgname.jpg")" />
</a>
```

ASPX (View Engine):

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") %>">
    <img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/img/imgname.jpg") %>" />
</a>
```

Obviously, if you do this more than once, write a helper for it. And fill in the other attributes of img/a. But this should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 22):

Try something like this:

```
public static string ActionLinkWithImage(this HtmlHelper html, string imgSrc, string actionName)
{
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

    string imgUrl = urlHelper.Content(imgSrc);
    TagBuilder imgTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
    imgTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", imgUrl);
    string img = imgTagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

    string url = UrlHelper.Action(actionName);

    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a") {
        InnerHtml = img
    };
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url);

    return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I suggest changing `TagRenderMode.Normal` to `TagRenderMode.SelfClosing` for the img; otherwise it renders as `<img...></img>` instead of `<img.../>`

Comment: Action is not static method of UrlHelper class so it should be called from an urlHelper object.

Answer (score 6):

The first answer given by @Craig Stuntz is absolutely perfect but my concern is about if what will you do if you have `Ajax.ActionLink` instead of `Html.ActionLink`. Here I will explain easy solutions for both methods. You can do as the following for `Html.ActonLink`:

```
@Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "Home").ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"/Contents/img/logo.png\" ... />"))
```

same concept can be applied for `Ajax.ActionLink`

```
@Html.Raw(@Ajax.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="dvTest"}).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"/Contents/img/logo.png\" … />"))
```

so this will be easy for you.

Edit:

ActionLink Image with Style Sheet or Class Name

With Style sheet

```
@Html.Raw(@Ajax.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="dvTest"}).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"/assets/img/logo.png\"  style=\"width:10%\" ... />"))
```

With Class Name

```
<style>
.imgClass {
 width:20%
}
```

```
@Html.Raw(@Ajax.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="dvTest"}).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"/assets/img/logo.png\" class=\"imgClass\"  ... />"))
```

For more reference regarding ActionLink around Image visit [ActionLink around Image in Asp.net MVC](http://www.datahaunting.com/mvc/asp-net-mvc-image-actionlink/)

Comment: @LenielMacaferi Thanks . It's my pleasure that you got right solutions.

Comment: this works thanks. Is there a way I can add css style to the image

Comment: @sumedha I have updated my answer regarding CSS style to image. I hope it will be useful to u.

Answer (score 2):

more easy...

change your code by:

```
<p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Home",
    new
    {
        style = "background: url('" + Url.Content("~/images/logo.png") + "') no-repeat center right; display:block; height:50px;width:50px;"
    })</p>
```

Comment: Our you can just do this straight from CSS instead of using inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use url.content:

```
@Url.Content("~/images/img/slide.png")
```

this return relative path

Answer (score 0):

You can create htmlhelper which can return image with link...
As parameters you will pass to htmlhelper values like image path and link and in htmlhelper you will use StringBuilder to format html of  that linked image properly...

cheers